# Angular shared model with multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and trying to clear my concepts:

My app requires a single model which will be updated by different controllers. So, the model should be shared. Following link explains clearly how should I proceed with it

http://www.webdeveasy.com/angularjs-data-model/

It creates two services using factory method. The manager service checks whether the model class has been already instantiated or not. If yes it returns an already instantiated reference otherwise it `new's` an instance. Hence  each model sees the same model instance and on updating model updates occur in all the views.

If instead of creating service using `factory`, one creates a service using `service` method which returns a `new'd` instance automatically, would that be shared or bound to the controller.

I assume my case cannot be achieved using `service` method, i must use `factory` method instead of `service` method as it `new's` the services everytime it is injected in any controller. Does angular not maintain some pool internally to make sure same service instance is injected in all the controllers.

I don't want an additional manager object for the model to ensure same instance being used in all the controllers

Answer (score 4):

As far as your case is concerned, **Both services and factory can be used, as both of them are essentially similar in nature by functionalities.**

As per my understanding, you want a single news entity, to be shared across all controllers, as per singleton design pattern, ensuring one update -> updates all. This can be perfectly implemented using Angular Services.

I myself find using services easier than factory method, since the former has an easy to use syntax :D

Also, for more understanding of Difference between the two approaches, you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074875/factory-and-service-in-angularjs) answer

[image]

Comment: Also check the following thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory/13763886#13763886 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory/15666049#15666049

Comment: @TechMa9iac Everytime a class is newed it creates a separate instance, services are newed automatically, that won't allow for sharing the instance. I can't keep track of instances in service method to share them across controllers but in factory I can

Comment: They won't be **newed**. You will have the same instance shared across all the controllers and other app components. Implement it programmatically ..

Comment: @TechMa9iac I don't have any "news" entity by new's i meant javascript new keyword

Comment: I understand.. Give it a try.. Services will work, there won't be any new instances, the same will be shared all across.