# angularJS $scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-scope

I have two types of variables in my $scope angularJS.

1). $scope.name, $scope.title -- these are bind to two input boxes(these are bind to UI html code).

2). $scope.sum, $scope.difference -- these variables are used in JS code internally, I need them just as global variables to access in different functions.

Problem :- Is $scope.$watch function will run for variables of 2nd case, is these type of variables gave any bad effect on my page performance.

Comment: Are those function are not related to Angular ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's depend of your expression. But, never make a watch on a expensive expression because angularjs will evaluate a number of times, and it necessarily would have a very negative impact on your application performance.

In general, it is necessary to optimize your appplication when there is a performance problem. In most cases everything goes very well, and it is not desirable to unnecessarily complicate the application.

Also, you can use the **one-way data binding**, where the expression start with `::`. The expression will stop recalculating once they are stable, after the first digest.

Comment: I moved some pages from jQuery plateform to angular plateform and combined more than 10 pages functionality wise on single page, one of my ng-repeat creates 150 watches per iteration, so this is necessary, when array.length = 100 there are 15000 watches approx. which is creating problem??

Comment: In fact, the ng-repeat directive of AngularJS is getting slow above 2500 two-way data bindings

Comment: Then what should we do in case of large and complex pages having large number of watches and data bindings.

Comment: You can use pagination, one-way data binding, avoid inline method into ngRepeat directive. There is a good article here : [Improve performance](http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/)

Answer (score 0):

Variables which are in $scope are accessible in through out(in diff functions) your controller. If you want to use those variables in another controller you can use service/factory for sharing scope variables in diff controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If those function are not related to angular anyway you can use following
Just declare a global variable in page and assign it's value to that modal

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.globalVariable = "something";
  globalVariable = $scope.globalVariable;
});

var globalVariable;

function externalFunction(){
  alert(globalVariable);
}
```

Here's [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PvOVvDh8yAJHyXpmqAkb?p=preview)

If those function are inside of another controller you can use service or factory to share information between controller
For service and factory please refer this link

[AngularJS : Factory and Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074875/factory-and-service-in-angularjs)