# Angular ngresource update method not a function

Tags: angularjs, mean, angularjs-ng-resource

I am using the MEAN Stack. I am trying to add a PUT request into my $ngResource and I get an error:

```
TypeError: conService.update is not a function

at m.$scope.joinCon (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/chirpApp-ngresource.js:217:14)

at lb.functionCall (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js:200:64)

at Hc.(anonymous function).compile.d.on.f (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js:216:394)

at m.$get.m.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js:126:250)

at m.$get.m.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js:126:476)

at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js:216:446)

at HTMLButtonElement.c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js:32:389)
```

My code

```
//My factory
app.factory('conService', function ($resource) {return $resource('/api/cons', {'update': { method: 'PUT' }});});

//My update
conService.update({conName:$scope.cons.conName},$scope.cons);};

//My api to get all conventions
.get(function (req, res) {Con.find(function (err, cons) {if (err) { return res.send(500, err); }return res.send(cons);});})
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am missing in my update? Thanks

Comment: in `$resource`, non-get functions are prefixed with `$`.  does `conService.$update` work?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: adding {} stopped the error. Here is the updated line of code ...//My factory
app.factory('conService', function ($resource) {return $resource('/api/cons', {}, {'update': { method: 'PUT' }});});   Now I get a 404 error but I think I can track that down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a factory you should instantiate in controller code before usage it with following:

```
var cs = new conService();
cs.update(/*params here*/);
```

For more details read those great posts: [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory), [AngularJS : Factory and Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074875/factory-and-service-in-angularjs)

Comment: I tried directly translating what you posted into my code but it is not working. (edit: I still get the not function error about my update ) I will read the link you suggested tonight. Thanks for the additional information!