# Difference between service and factory

Tags: angularjs

How can we transform/changes below code to factory rather than service

What is the better way to implement within these two, factory and service, please suggest.
I'm new to AngularJs so please help me out in this concern

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    </head>

<body ng-app="app">


    <div ng-controller="CalculatorController">
        Enter a number:
        <input type="number" ng-model="number" />
        <button ng-click="doSquare()">X<sup>2</sup></button>
        <button ng-click="doCube()">X<sup>3</sup></button>

        <div>Answer: {{answer}}</div>
    </div>



    <script>

        var app = angular.module('app', []);

            app.service('MathService', function() {
                this.add = function(a, b) { return a + b };

                this.subtract = function(a, b) { return a - b };

                this.multiply = function(a, b) { return a * b };

                this.divide = function(a, b) { return a / b };
            });

            app.service('CalculatorService', function(MathService){

                this.square = function(a) { return MathService.multiply(a,a); };
                this.cube = function(a) { return MathService.multiply(a, MathService.multiply(a,a)); };

            });

            app.controller('CalculatorController', function($scope, CalculatorService) {

                $scope.doSquare = function() {
                    $scope.answer = CalculatorService.square($scope.number);
                }

                $scope.doCube = function() {
                    $scope.answer = CalculatorService.cube($scope.number);
                }
            });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Service VS provider VS factory in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

Comment: Check this link it will clear all your confusions-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory

Comment: To my knowledge this one is the best. Please refer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074875/angularjs-factory-and-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Both are singleton
- They differ in terms of writing pattern
- My personnel choice is to use service

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
                app.factory('MathService', function(){
                    return {
                        multiply : function(a, b){
                            return a*b;
                        }
                    }
                });

                app.factory('CalculateResult', ['MathService', function(MathService){
                        return {
                            square : function(a){
                                return MathService.multiply(a,a);
                            },

                            cube : function(a){
                                return MathService.multiply(a, MathService.multiply(a,a));
                            }
                        }
                }]);

                app.controller('CalculatorController', ['CalculateResult', '$scope', function(CalculateResult, $scope){

                    $scope.doSquare = function(){
                        $scope.answer = CalculateResult.square($scope.number);
                    };

                    $scope.doCube = function(){
                        $scope.answer = CalculateResult.cube($scope.number);
                    }

                }]);
```

Here is the answer thanks for supports