# Service showing undefined in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I have wrote one service which will upload image to server and I am using that service from controller but on call to service showing that undefined function which is defined in service. and error is something like this **"Cannot read property 'uploadFileToUrl' of undefined"**

**here is my code**

```
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file,clientid, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        fd.append('id', clientid);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(response){
            console.log(response)
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);
```

**and here i am calling this service**

```
app.controller('settingsCtrl', ['$scope','apiCall','$filter', function($scope,apiCall,$filter,fileUpload){
    $scope.saveStudioBranch = function(){
        studio();
        admin();
        branch();
    }

    function studio(){
        var studio_json = {"session_id":session_id,"u":[{"col":"studio","val":$scope.studioDetails.studio},{"col":"type","val":$scope.studioDetails.type}],"filter":[["id","=","1"]],"table":"studio"};
        apiCall.callEndpoint(studio_json,"settingRoute.php","update",json_header).then(function(response){
            if(response.data.error == 0){
                if($scope.inst_logo != undefined ){
                    var uploadUrl = "https://papa.fit/routes/registrationRoute.php?action=instLogo";
                    -->> fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl($scope.inst_logo,session.client_id,uploadUrl);
                }
            }
            else
                show_snack(response.data.message);
        });

    }
});
```

I have added a arrow where I am calling service from

Comment: Show the code where are you injecting the service

Comment: ohh sorry . I will edit above code and please recheck it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the error is in the injection

```
app.controller('settingsCtrl', ['$scope','apiCall','$filter', 
  function($scope, apiCall, $filter, fileUpload){
```

you forgot to add `fileUpload` service inside the list of parameters

```
app.controller('settingsCtrl', ['$scope','apiCall','$filter', 'fileUpload',
  function($scope, apiCall, $filter, fileUpload){
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return your service, or else it would be undefined

```
  function uploadFileToUrlSrv($http) {

    var service = {};
    service.uploadFileToUrl = function(file,clientid, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        fd.append('id', clientid);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(response){
            console.log(response)
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
    return service;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you. can you explian in brief ?

Comment: @sameerdighe a service is a set of functions. You need to return your service as an object to use it in your controllers

Comment: I've edited with a code sample what your service should look like, but in angular keep in mind that you **must** always return a service when you create it :)

Comment: @GuillaumeRoche-Bayard  OP code related to service declaration is correct. Read [AngularJS : Factory and Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074875/angularjs-factory-and-service)